# How to avoid duplicate entries in MySQL db using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-places-api

I am using google Radar Place search and Place Details API together. I am getting json responses from this API. I need to store these responses in my MySQL database. For that, I am converting JSON response into Java object and I store it in my MySQL db.

This API only gives the maximum of 200 responses. So that, If I need to get all the responses in a certain place, I have to break up that region into smaller regions. And also, for these smaller regions I find out the responses. So, in this process I use HIBERNATE to store my data. While updating into database, I need to avoid the duplicate entries into db. I use place_id as a primary key. But, the place_id is unique that I receive from this API. I cannot auto-increment it. So, how to avoid duplicate entries?

Comment: Hi mate, maybe can try setting columns which you expect as unique key, and transaction management when inserting records.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Java object to an entity and then tell Hibernate that he needs to use an specific field as Primary Key

```
@Entity
public class Region{
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;
    public void setId(Long id){this.id=id;}
    public Long getId(){return id}
    //And so on...
}
```

take a look at this for more information:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html

Comment: By using this, Can I avoid duplicate entries?